# Public Enum with one item in a different scope (Like Friend)

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums, scope

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
Public Enum CarMakes
   Honda
   BMW
   Mazda
   Friend Yugo
End Enum
```

I need to expose the the Enum to Public except for one of the items I just want to be available from inside the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do.  Individual enum values don't have the concept of accessibility but instead just have the accessibility of the declaring enum.

Note: Even if they did have accessibility it would be very easy for the caller to violate it.  Enum values are not checked for correctness.  Hence even if the above syntax was legal I could subvert it in the following way.

```
' Yugo has the numeric value 3 due to it's declaration location
Dim carMakes As CarMakes = 3

' CarMakes can be any Integer value.  Even ones which have no mapping 
' to the values you've defined 
Dim other As CarMakes = 1042
```

This will compile and run without any errors and produce verifiable IL.

Comment: So I guess I could just have one Enum Public and One Enum Private - ok thanks.

Comment: One thing that saved me, as I realized later, is since the enum is being used in a WCF Service, I was able to `DataContract` the enum and then decorate ONLY the enums I wanted to expose with `EnumMember`